# How to add prefix to each column of categorical features in datapreprocessing (onehotencoding)

Tags: pandas, one-hot-encoding, dummy-variable

```
                        SUBJECTS
0   NATHANIEL FORD  Maths,Science,Computer  22  Class   16
1   GARY JIMENEZ    Science,Physics,Maths   10  Hall    15
2   ALBERT PARDINI  Science,Computer    22  Corridor    14
3   JAMES BARNER    Maths,Science,Computer  30  Board   16
4   PATRICK GARDNER Maths,Science,Computer  22  Class   16
```

for the above subjects column,how to one hot encode it with columns having
prefix as sub_Maths,sub_Science,etc

my code was:

```
prac1=pd.concat([prac1,prac1.Subjects.str.get_dummies(sep=',')],1)
prac1=prac1.drop("Subjects",axis=1)
prac1
```

o/p:

```
                                 Computer   Maths   Physics Science
0   NATHANIEL FORD  22  Class   16  1   1   0   1
1   GARY JIMENEZ    10  Hall    15  0   1   1   1
2   ALBERT PARDINI  22  Corridor 14 1   0   1   1   
3   JAMES BARNER    30  Board   16  1   1   0   1
4   PATRICK GARDNER 22  Class   16  1   1   0   1
5   ELLISA GRAY 15  Corridor    17  1   1   0   1
```

???

Comment: in the concat use  `prac1.Subjects.str.get_dummies(sep=',').add_prefix('sub_')` so that you add `'sub_'` to all of the column names in the dummy DataFrame.